# Filtering the row in DataFrame based on matching values of a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am filtering the Spark DataFrame using filter:

```
var notFollowingList=List(9.8,7,6,3,1)
df.filter(col("uid”).isin(notFollowingList))
```

But I get an error saying:

```
Unsupported literal type classscala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon 
Can anyone help me in resolving the error?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below snippet:

```
var notFollowingList=List(9.8,7,6,3,1)
df.filter(col("uid").isin(notFollowingList:_*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for reference,

```
var notFollowingList=List(9.8,7,6,3,1)

val df = Seq(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,7.0).toDF("uid")
df.show()
+---+
|uid|
+---+
|1.0|
|2.0|
|3.0|
|4.0|
|7.0|
+---+
val filt_df = df.filter(col("uid").isin(notFollowingList:_*))
filt_df.show()
+---+
|uid|
+---+
|1.0|
|3.0|
|7.0|
+---+
```